# Which Users SSH key should I put in Owner's SSH Key - Git Plugin in Tuleap?

Tags: git, plugins, tuleap

I have installed Tuleap and I would like to connect it to my GitLab server. I am using the Git plugin provided by Tuleap but I am not sure how to fill in the boxes.

There is a section called `Owner's SSH Key` asking for a users SSH key I guess. Which user should this be? Git? Root? Something else?

Comment: It's unclear what you want to do with this ssh key, what's your intend ?

Comment: this might help https://tuleap-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/administration-guide/howto.html  it mentions to generate an ssh key.  `"As user gitolite, generate an ssh key (ssh-keygen)"`